What is a good Chinese encyclopedia about the life and work of mathematicians?
Nowadays, one would usually look up informations as referenced in the title in the Chinese version of Wikipedia. But still, as a professional reference for such information and as a supplement to the 数学大辞典 from my previous question which I am avidly reading now and which does not contain much historical information about the life and work of mathematicians except every now and then a name with its Chinese transliteration together with a key concept they invented which is already very useful for me, I would like to ask if you know and can recommend a good Chinese encylopedia about the life and work of mathematicians written by some recognized Chinese math historians. I am looking, for example, for a book with an entry for each mathematician sorted in alphabetically order where each entry might be around a page long not more - but other formats, like not necessarily encyclopedic, are also welcome.

You may want to try "百度百科" - https://baike.baidu.com/

I see your point ☝️ maybe better than a book... @r13

《数学史辞典》seems working https://annas-archive.gs/md5/241ab368330157950fb80673fb5c3f52

Some math history books 有哪些值得推荐的《数学史》教材或者参考书？ - Rs博士的回答 - 知乎
https://www.zhihu.com/question/441000319/answer/1695846443

Yau has a math history course in Tsinghua but I don't know how to get the text

Thank you @ZhenRanZR , I think the downloadable file 数学史辞典 perfectly suits my needs and answers my question. Your additional post on 知乎 is also very interesting and competent and supplementing; I like it a lot!


Although 科學家小詞典 瀋陽，遼寧教育出版社，2000 is aimed at high school students, you might find it useful. This 460 page volume, part of an encyclopedic series, includes several biographies of famous Chinese mathematicians in the first 299 pages (the remainder covers foreign scientists). I am including part of a three-page biography of 祖沖之 where I have highlighted the story of how he came up with the "astronomer's fraction" 355/113, a nine-digit approximation of π: 3.1415929

Thank you, I will probably go for the 数学史辞典 recommended in the comments above. Do you have any ideas how to locate the text in your answer?

Chances are that series (actually multiple hardbound series) is out of print by now, but there could be a revised edition. The science volume might be available second hand (I bought my titles new).
